# What is the structure of this sentence containing "that"

Tags: sentence-construction, relative-pronouns

> The use of biometric indicia for identification purposes requires that a particular biometric factor be unique for each individual, **that** it be readily measured, and **that** it be invariant over time.

Could you say simpler examples which I can use such structure within?

Comment: I think I got the structure, they refer to subordinate clauses of *require*?

Comment: Yes, you got it! Also, this may be useful: http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/glossaryoflinguisticterms/WhatIsAComplementClause.htm

Comment: Jup. That's it. Like: "Requires [subordinate clause 1], [subordinate clause 2], and [subordinate clause 3]. Why don't you write the answer yourself? I think you are ready...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word *that* here acts as a subordinating conjunction. It refers to the subordinate clause each time:

> The use of biometric indicia for identification purposes requires...

This is your main clause (however, you could also see the entire sentence including the subordinate clauses as the main clause).

The following three sentences are your subordinate clauses, linked to *require* by *that*:

> - that a particular biometric factor be unique for each individual
> - that it be readily measured
> - that it be invariant over time.

The three subordinate clauses are linked together through coordinated conjunctions (the comma and *and*) on their level.

### Some additional information:

Your sentence is what we call a **complex-compound** sentence. A sentence with a main and a dependent clause is a **complex** sentence. One with two or more independent clauses is a **compound** sentence. In this case, your sentence is a **complex** sentence, but because it contains two or more dependent clauses that are coordinated (thus **compound**), your sentence is **compound complex**. If you turn this around and have multiple main clauses that have subclauses (dependent clauses), you get a **compound-complex** sentence.

Comment: Well, to make it a bit harder question, can I omit all the three *that*s?

Comment: I think you can. It certainly doesn't sound wrong, but I think it's better not to omit them in order to avoid confusion.

Comment: You could say: *To be used for identification purposes, a particular biometric factor must be unique for each individual, readily measured, and invariant over time.*